# Changing session timeout for ASP.NET MVC 4 app

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

My app is configured to run through IIS. I'm trying to change the session timeout from the default 20 minutes to 1 minute.

I've tried the following, with no success:

- Changed the `Idle Time-out (minutes)` property in the App Pool ([figure 1](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/6ff10de3-358b-477d-b35e-b98ffd086662/c905ef4ce26d5eb454a9c97a20b000b4?noteKey=c905ef4ce26d5eb454a9c97a20b000b4&noteGuid=6ff10de3-358b-477d-b35e-b98ffd086662))
- Changed the `Time-out` property in the ASP page of the App configuration in IIS ([figure 2](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/90860a7d-eb3b-4f29-af5c-ccb12b8cdb16/0454a57140ce97d7ccc48f1e856a4ee2))
- Added `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1"/>` under `<configuration><system.web>`

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could this be caused by the fact that my app is in debug mode?!

Comment: It turns out that our application doesn't use Session at all, which made this exercise useless.